# How to use RDFa with Google and HTML head <base> tag

Tags: html, url, google-search, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

On a website, we are using a HTML head `base` tag. The reason is the convenience of linking to static resources through relative URLs and it's very hard to change. Content URLs are always fully qualified. So the `head` section looks like:

```html
<head>
    <base href="http://example.com/static/" />
</head>
```

Now, we are using RDFa to specify structured data on the page. To populate i.e. a `schema:Product` page, say `http://example.com/product1`. Now, the problem comes from the `base` tag: in the absence of any other reparation, the RDFa parser considers the whole RDFa data is about `http://example.com/static`, not about `http://example.com/product1`.

We have tried with mixed results adding the property `about="http://example.com/product1"` on either `<html>` or `<body>`.

This intermittently works with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool. Intermittently in the sense that about 2 months ago it seemed to work when added to `<body>`, now it appears to work when added to `<head>`.

However, in the Search Console under "Structured Data" the situation is not even intermittently working. It used to work about 8 months ago with `<html about="...">` but now it just doesn't work either way. I mean the pages are indexed, but not the structured data.

So, is there a standard, tried and proven way to make Google (and any generic meta parser) properly know the URL of a webpage that has a generic `<base href="" />` tag that is different to its actual URL?

#### Example 1

Assume the following is rendered by HTTP GET `http://bar.com/product1`

```html
<html prefix="schema: http://schema.org/">  
    <head>  
        <base href="http://foo.com/" />  
    </head>  
    <body about="http://bar.com/product1" typeof="schema:Product">  
        <span property="schema:name">Bar product</span>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

The above:

- Was working with Google based on Google Search Console / Structured Data ~8 months ago and Google Structured Data Testing Tool ~2 months ago
- Is not working with Google based on Google Search Console / Structured Data since 8m ago (no errors reported, but new content is not fetched into structured data report), is not parsing with Testing Tool ATM

#### Example 2

```html
<html prefix="schema: http://schema.org/" about="http://bar.com/product1" typeof="schema:Product">
    <head>  
        <base href="http://foo.com/" />  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <span property="schema:name">Bar product</span>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

- Was not parsing with Google Structured Data Testing Tool ~2 months ago
- Is parsing with Google Structured Data Testing Tool ATM
- Is not working with Google based on Google Search Console / Structured Data ATM (no errors reported, but new content is not fetched into structured data report)

Answer (score 0):

Both of your example snippets seem to work correctly in Google’s [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en). As one would expect, they generate the same output.

> **`@type`** `Product`
>   **`@id`** `http://bar.com/product1`
>   **`name`** Bar product

I can’t test it in Google’s Search Console, but I could imagine that the issue you see is not related to the RDFa markup.

Anyway, you could try to use `resource` instead of `about`. While both ways are fine in RDFa, RDFa Lite supports only [`resource`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-rdfa-lite-20150317/#resource). I’m not saying that Google only supports RDFa Lite (probably not, because their SDTT seems to support `about` fine), but when they refer to RDFa, they typically link to the RDFa Lite spec.

```html
<html prefix="schema: http://schema.org/">  
    <head>  
        <base href="http://foo.com/" />  
    </head>  
    <body resource="http://bar.com/product1" typeof="schema:Product">  
        <span property="schema:name">Bar product</span>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @unor, what you are reporting is half right though:
The <body about="..." variant is parsed right if you paste the HTML into the SDTT; if you load it via GET (by url), it magicaly stops working. This is just one inconsistency with the SDTT, another being that the opposite was true a while ago (as mentioned before): then, <html about="..." didn't work. The third inconsistency is that neither work anymore by looking at the Search Console, no new content is parsed with either of the two. I haven't tried using resource=, but about= used to work fine until it stopped working...

Comment: @Dinu: I see -- so the issue in SDTT only comes up when checking via URL. Over the years, I read about many problems of this kind (works with code paste check, doesn’t work with URL check). While some might have to do with how the server responds, for others this wasn’t the issue. I’d guess it’s just a bug in the SDTT.

Comment: yeap, looks like it, however I'm obviously more concerned about the actual Google parsing and results i.e. the empty Search Console... I was hoping there's some authoritative spec on how to do this in either Google or RDFa communities or somewhere, or some tried and proven way that survived what seem to be occasional changes in their parser.

Comment: Note: (updated question) From your response it seems my description wasn't clear: the pages are indexed (in terms of static content), it's just the Structured Data that doesn't get parsed in the Search Console. It gets parsed ok for pages without a <base href="..." /> tag, it's just these pages, just lately, and just the Structured Data that's missing.